# how do i count occurrence of words in a line

Tags: java, frequency, words

I am fairly new to java. I want to count the occurrences of words in a particular line. So far i can only count the words but no idea how to count occurrences.

Is there a simple way to do this?

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/../output.txt"));
int count = 0;
  while (file.hasNextLine()) {
    String s = file.nextLine();
    count++;    
      if(s.contains("#AVFC")){
       System.out.printf("There are %d words on this line ", s.split("\\s").length-1);
       System.out.println(count);   
      }

  }
file.close();
```

Output:

```
    There are 4 words on this line 1

    There are 8 words on this line 13

    There are 3 words on this line 16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of is to use `String.split("\\s")`, which will split based on spaces.

Then have a `HashMap` containing a word as the key with the value being the number of times it is used.

```
   HashMap<String, Integer> mapOfWords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

      while (file.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = file.nextLine(); 
        String[] words = s.split("\\s");
        int count;
        for (String word : words) {
           if (mapOfWords.get(word) == null) {
              mapOfWords.put(word, 1);
           }
           else {
              count = mapOfWord.get(word);
              mapOfWords.put(word, count + 1);
           }
        }
      }
```

Implementation you requested to skip strings that contain certain words

```
   HashMap<String, Integer> mapOfWords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

   while (file.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = file.nextLine(); 
        String[] words = s.split("\\s");
        int count;

        if (isStringWanted(s) == false) {
           continue;  
        } 

        for (String word : words) {
           if (mapOfWords.get(word) == null) {
              mapOfWords.put(word, 1);
           }
           else {
              count = mapOfWord.get(word);
              mapOfWords.put(word, count + 1);
           }
        }
      }

private boolean isStringWanted(String s) {
    String[] checkStrings = new String[] {"chelsea", "Liverpool", "#LFC"};

    for (String check : checkString) {
        if (s.contains(check)) {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: yes i heard something about hash map but no clue how to code it as I'm quit new to this. is it possible to help with code? thanks

Comment: Can't use `int` for generics, have to use `Integer`

Comment: if i want to count lines that contains certain string, how do i do this? see my edit which  currently  doesn't work

Comment: @JD14 `String.contains()` method in the String library will solve that for you. Here is the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @NappaTheSaiyan I've tried saying if string contains words it should get lines but still getting errors

Comment: @NappaTheSaiyan I'm getting syntax error saying ")"; expected. I've tried doing this: private String s = new String isStringWanted ();{ but doesn't work

Comment: @JD14 There are three things wrong with that statement. 1 : The string constructor doesn't accept a `boolean` parameter. 2 : `isStringWanted(String s)` requires a String input. 3 : You are missing the paranthesis to call the String constructor. Finally I would like to add that I have no idea why you tried to invoke that statement. `isStringWanted()` checks to see if the line from the file contains one of your key words.

Answer (score 4):

Try below code, it may solve your problem, in addition you can call String.toLowerCase() before you put it into the hashmap

```
String line ="a a b b b b a q c c";
...
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line); 
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String s = scanner.next();
    Integer count = map.put(s,1); 
    if(count!=null) map.put(s,count + 1);
}
...
System.out.println(map);
```

Result:

```
{b=4, c=2, q=1, a=3}
```

Comment: I think you meant map.put(s, count + 1) ?

Comment: this works thanks a lot. only problem is it counts just one line, and i want to count words in only lines that contains #AVFC jus like my code. any help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Check Guava's [Multiset](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset). Their description starts with `'The traditional Java idiom for e.g. counting how many times a word occurs in a document is something like:'`. You find some code snippets how to do that without a MultiSet.

BTW: If you only wanted to count the number of words in your string, why not just count the spaces? You could use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from the apache commons. It's much better than creating an array of the split parts. Also have a look at [their implementation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(string, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest would be store the splitted data in a ArrayList then iterate on your ArrayList and use [Collections.frequency] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_frequency.htm)

Answer (score -2):

In a given `String`, occurrences of a given `String` can be counted using `String#indexOf(String, int)` and through a loop

```
String haystack = "This is a string";
String needle = "i";
int index = 0;

while (index != -1) {
    index = haystack.indexOf(needle, index + 1);

    if (index != -1) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Found %s in %s at index %s.", needle, haystack, index));
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will just find a particular character in a string, it won't calculate the word frequency.

Comment: Yes, counting should be able for anyone with minimal Java knowledge.

Comment: This does make sense. it finds the first index of the searched string ("needle") and continues from there until no occurance is found. Only thing missing is a count variable to hold how many instances were found.

Comment: So this is a horrible way to go about counting word frequency in a string. You're iterating over the string character by character once  for each unique word in the string. For a long string this is going to be a lot of iterations. Seems like the better way is to split on spaces, then count the words using a Map.

Comment: Yes, because splitting at spaces does *not* need to traverse a string from front to back...